# Tilewindows vertically c#

Tags: c#

I have the following code to tile windows vertically, but the problem with this code is that it tiles all windows vertically, but i want to  tile only the explorer window and notepad window to be tiled vertically which is invoked by this code. 
This is requirement of one of our internal client where they want to open file explorer and notepad simultaneously and on opening they should tile vertically side by side.

could anyone please help on this

thanks upfront!!!

```
class Program
{
    internal struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern void MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern unsafe bool CascadeWindows(IntPtr hWnd, int wHow, RECT[] lpRect, uint cKids, IntPtr[] lpKids);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
    //fdfdfdf
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "TileWindows")]
    static extern unsafe IntPtr TileWindows(IntPtr hWnd, int wHow, RECT[] lpRect, uint cKids, IntPtr[] lpKids);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]

    static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);    

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const short SWP_NOMOVE = 0X2;
        const short SWP_NOSIZE = 1;
        const short SWP_NOZORDER = 0X4;
        const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        const int MDITILE_SKIPDISABLED = 0x0002;
        const int MDITILE_ZORDER = 0x0004;
        const long WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008L;
        const int MDITILE_HORIZONTAL = 0x0001;
        const int MDITILE_VERTICAL = 0x0000;
        const short SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
        try
        {
            int hWnd;
            RECT Rect = new RECT();
            Process outlook = new Process();
            outlook.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
            outlook.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            outlook.Start();
            IntPtr id = outlook.MainWindowHandle;
            if (id != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                id = GetForegroundWindow();
                SetWindowPos(id, 0, 0, 0, 800, 900, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Process explorer = new Process();
            explorer.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            explorer.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
           explorer.Start();

            IntPtr id2 = explorer.MainWindowHandle;

            if (id2 != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                id2 = GetForegroundWindow();
                SetWindowPos(id2, 0, -800, 0, 800, 900, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }

            TileWindows(id2, MDITILE_VERTICAL, null, 0, null);


            Console.Read();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I am myself in the process of doing the same thing in C# i.e. translating the code from C++ to C#, so I don't have a working code but I can sure provide some info on how to make it work.

To tile multiple windows, you need to provide their HWND values in the last parameter i.e. `IntPtr[]` lpKids and the function will tile all the windows whose HWND is present in the lpKids array. 
And uint cKids must contain the number of HWNDs in the lpKids array.

Once these two parameters are set properly, it should be working.

I may post the working code once I get mine to run smoothly.

```
 TileWindows((IntPtr)null, style, rect, (uint)hwndList.Count, lpKids);
```

Where
(IntPtr)null means you are referring to desktop window

style is MDITILE_VERTICAL or MDITILE_HORIZONTAL to tile vertically or horizontally

rect is a rectangle(x,y,width,height) that contains desktop window size

(uint)hwndList.Count is number of HWNDs you want to operate upon. I got these using my own selection criterion using function EnumDesktopWindows()

lpKids is an array containing HWNDs that I want to operate upon.

to get desktop rectangle I used:

```
    private RECT getRect()
    {
        RECT rect = new RECT();
        rect.y = 0;
        rect.x = 0;
        rect.width = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width;
        rect.height = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height;

        return rect;
    }
```

Where RECT is

```
        internal struct RECT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
            public int width;
            public int height;
        }
```

I hope that helps.